# How do I compare lists?

Tags: python, list

I asked a question earlier about how to print the list with longest len, and I learned how to use the max function.
My problem now is this:

```
somelist = [[['yes', 'yes', 'yes'], ['maybe']], [['yes', 'yes'], ['maybe']]]
```

I only want to compare the `"yes"` lists. Can anyone help?
If I use the `max(somelist, key=len)` it will compare the whole "yes and maybe" list which has len 2 in both cases.

Comment: You could either filter out the 'maybe' lists or have your key function return a length of zero for them.

Comment: I get what you mean, but how do I do that in coding?

Comment: clue: `x=0 ; print( len(somelist[x][0]) ) ; x=1 ; print( len(somelist[x][0]) )`

Comment: I can't use len(somelist[x][0]) when I have the word key before.
key=len(somelist[x][0]) is not working, python is saying "int object is not callable"

Comment: The sublists of `somelist` are of the form [list-of-yeses, list-of-maybes]. Is that *always* going to be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sublists of the main list are always of the form `[`list-of-yeses`,` list-of-maybes`]`, you can do this:

```
>>> mainlist = [[['yes', 'yes', 'yes'], ['maybe']], [['yes', 'yes'], ['maybe']]]
>>> longest = max(mainlist, key=lambda sublist: len(sublist[0]))
>>> longest
[['yes', 'yes', 'yes'], ['maybe']]
```

The error message you got makes sense: you have to pass a callable as `key`; however, `len(somelist[x][0]` is an `int`. `len` is a callable, which is why you didn't get an exception when you used it as `key`, although it doesn't give the answer you want.

Comment: that is amazing thank you! It solved all my problems!

Comment: @StephanieAboud You're welcome :) Feel free to give it a vote or a green checkmark... tips are appreciated.